# Buidling an XNA tile editor

Tags: c#, windows, xna

I'm writing a tile editor for a game and would like to be able to select which level file to open.  Once open I would load the level into an XNA window and click to add/remove tiles to the level.  When the editing is finished I would save the file layout back to the original file.

Currently I don't see a way to integrate windows forms and XNA.  Is this even possible?

Comment: If you want an in depth tutorial, I recommend you check out Nick Gravelyns tile game tutorial. It walks through building a basic engine, along with a map editor: http://blog.nickgravelyn.com/2010/02/tile-engine-videos-on-youtube/

Answer (score 2):

When I was working on a small, "2.5D" isometric game in XNA, I found it worth while to also have a separate WinForms version that would just render a 2D top-down view using GDI. This was due to my inexperience with XNA and my (relative) comfort using WinForms.

This approach also had the useful side-effect of enforcing separation between logic and rendering code. It made it easier (for me, at least) to test changes without having to worry about how to deal with the XNA rendering aspects.

It may not be exactly what you had in mind, but it might be something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

WinForms and Xna can cooperate, but it's not recommended to use Xna's built in Game class with WinFroms. There are two samples demonstrating it:

http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1
  http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2